# ExtJS--creating multiple instances of the same form but with different names for fields

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs

I have a Ext.form.Panel. In the forms items I have a container which contains all the form fields. On click of an add button, I insert another row/instance of that container into the form. How can I change the field names when a new instance is created? For example the field name is FIELD_1. When a new instance is created id like to change it to FIELD_2 then FIELD_3 and so forth..

because upon submit, when i do this.getForm().getValues(); this will return all the form values from all the instances in an array by field name:

```
"FIELD_1":["Row1Val", "Row2Val", "Row3Val"], "FIELD_2":["Row1Val", "Row2Val", "Row3Val"]
```

and i dont want this. That is why I am need to add a suffix to the field names when a new instance is created

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite easy.You can keep a global counter to manage this,Which you keep on increasing as you click on add button.

```
var number_of_row = 0;//you may choose to keep it global or of controller scope

function : addContainer(self){
     var data = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox'
    },
    width: 400,
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'FIELD_'+(++number_of_row),
        id: 'FIELD_'+(++number_of_row)
    },
      //your other items
    ]
});
//your code to add this container to the form panel.
}
```